# Cross-sections at zero temperature and high temperature for a process and its reverse

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, scattering-cross-section, thermal-field-theory

If the Feynman amplitude for a $2-2$ forward scattering $ab\to cd$ is denoted by $\mathcal{M}_{ab\to cd}$ and that of the reverse scattering  process, $cd\to ab$, is denoted by $\mathcal{M}_{cd\to ab}$, then for a hermitian interaction Hamiltonian, $\mathcal{M}_{ab\to cd}=\mathcal{M}_{cd\to ab}$. However, in general, the phase space factors involved in evaluating the corresponding scattering cross-sections  ${\large\sigma}_{ab\to cd}$ and ${\large \sigma}_{cd\to ab}$ are different so that, in general, ${\large\sigma}_{ab\to cd}\neq {\large \sigma}_{cd\to ab}$. Correct me if I am wrong!

Now, instead of the zero temperature, if these two processes take place in a thermal bath how would the picture change? In particular, do we expect the forward and reverse scatterings to become equal at high enough temperatures of the Universe (assume non-expanding)?

It will be helpful if the explanation is given in terms of some equations though I do not have sufficient background of thermal field theory.